# How to apply numerical operations to forecast object?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, forecast

I'm constructing ARIMA model, my data is monthly hence i adjusted calendar effect for each data point. After I modeled ARIMA and forecasted it I'd like to back transform the result. How I can access forecast's object mean and prediction intervals to apply numerical operations (so it still remains a forecast object)? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to miss something. I updated R and forecast package and we can just use raw transformation and the forecast object won't change its class. I have no clue why the object was changing its class from forecast to list before the update.

For example:

```
forecast[["mean"]] <- (forecast[["mean"]]/30)*monthdays(forecast[["mean"]])
```